# Podman (docker) container

Tags: docker, containers, podman

Does someone know how to start and stop services inside the container?

E.g. wish to stop sshd service INSIDE the Ubuntu container, but not in the whole host (RHEL).

Comment: Have you checked this issue on serverfault? https://serverfault.com/questions/724553/how-to-prevent-attach-or-exec-in-a-docker-container

Comment: A Docker container runs one process; it does not run "services" _per se_, and commands like `service` don't usually work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get a root shell in the container with `docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash` then you can run the command that you want

Comment: I can't! this is the problem. in Centos (RHEL based) all the containers are running without their own kernels

Comment: Are you sure sshd is running?

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to the container using the below command

   `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`
2. Using any of the below commands can stop the ssh service

   `$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh stop` or `$ sudo service ssh stop` or `$ sudo systemctl stop ssh`

Comment: The problem is that I'm using Centos. It says that 
`root@3904ba96d9b2:/# /etc/init.d/ssh start
bash: /etc/init.d/ssh: No such file or directory`